# File exists but shell can't launch the process

Tags: process, sh, embedded-linux, mips32

File exists on disk (and has execute permissions):

```
user@host# ls -l netsniff-ng
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        269468 Jan 16 09:42 netsniff-ng
```

Yet, when I attempt to launch it:

```
user@host# ./netsniff-ng
/bin/sh: ./netsniff-ng: not found
```

This is in `tmpfs`:

```
user@host# mount
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

host details, if it is of any help:

```
user@host# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : bull
machine                 : Unknown
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Ingenic Xburst V0.1  FPU V0.0
BogoMIPS                : 858.52
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : no
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 1, address/irw mask: [0x0fff]
isa                     : mips32r1
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 7
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

Hardware                : isvp
Serial                  : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

How could this be happening? How do I debug why `sh` isn't *finding* the file

**EDIT**

1. The file certainly exists (verified with `cat`, `ls`)
2. File was cross compiled (Host: x86)

**EDIT 2**

1. When a file doesn't exist and I execute the file, I get `not found`:

```
user@host# gcc
/bin/sh: gcc: not found
```

Comment: Are you copy-pasting that command and there's an invisible character stuck to it?

Comment: No. There's no invisible character. I copy-pasted the filename for ls as well

Comment: @sawdust, it absolutely does! Much appreciated.